# Wordpress: Date Picker Form Field breaking up in Mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am trying to fix date picker Form Field and its breaking up in mobile view. My [site](https://holidacious.com/holiday/?location_name=Morocco) has a form for travel destination select Form with a date picker Field. It works fine on laptop but not on mobile and I couldn't find the source to fix it.

[Snapshot](https://pasteboard.co/IMcloHD.png)

Just need kind help to guide me how I can fix it. You can take a look at CSS elements by inspecting the page because there is a lot of information to paste in question here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

That display: block causing the problem. disabling that solving your problem.

Comment: need to enabled all the time -   td {
    display: table-cell;   
}

Comment: did you use  -  td { display: table-cell !important; }? maybe you need to use multiple classes, id's to select that and work properly.